# Comparing two Double Values in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to compare two double values:

```
for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
    Double i1=Double.parseDouble(pref.getString("longitude"+i, null));
    Double i2=Double.parseDouble(pref.getString("latitude"+i,null));
    Log.i("Longitude", i1+"");
    Log.i("Latitude",i2+"");
    Log.i("Longitude1",longitude+"");
    Log.i("Latitude1", latitude+"");
    Log.i("note",pref.getString("note"+i, null));


    if(longitude==i1&&latitude==i2) {
        String note=pref.getString("note"+i, null);
        txt.setText(note);
    }
}
```

There is one combination in shared preference that matches with longitude and latitude but in if when i compare its not assigning any value to textview txt.but in log there is a same value for latitude and latitude.can any one please tell whats wrong in this comparison why its not executing txt.settext statement?

Comment: What types are `longitude` and `latitude`? You didn't provide any code for these two variables.

Comment: Are the values printed out in Log properly?

Comment: use `equals()` instead of `==`

Comment: yes actually longitude and latitude are values i am getting from intent and comparing it with shared preference value.yes the values are printed out in Log property.so same value are printing for one combination but in comparison no combination is true

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `latitude` and `longitude` to be `Double` too, try invoking the `doubleValue` of both:

```
if(longitude.doubleValue() == i1.doubleValue() && latitude.doubleValue() == i2.doubleValue())
```

or just use `equals`

```
if(longitude.equals(i1) && latitude.equals(i2))
```

which derives in the first line, under the hood.

Answer (score 6):

I think there is a accuracy issue - types as float or double cannon be represented absolutely strictly. When I need to compare two doubles I use something like this

```
double doubleToCompare1 = some double value;
double doubleToCompare2 = another double value;
double EPS = 0.00001;

if(Math.abs(doubleToCompare1-doubleToCompare2)<EPS){
   // assuming doubles are equals
}
```

EPS value depends on accuracy that you need. For coordinates as I remember it is 6 or 7 sign after comma.

Comment: Most accurate answer

Answer (score 2):

If latitude and longitude are `Double`s too, you need to run your comparison with `equals` instead of `==`:

```
(longitude.equals(i1) && latitude.equals(i2))
```

if they are `double`s (i.e. primitives) this is not necessary and the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **double** primitives instead of **Double** Classes.

```
for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
    double i1=Double.parseDouble(pref.getString("longitude"+i, null));
    double i2=Double.parseDouble(pref.getString("latitude"+i,null));
    Log.i("Longitude", i1+"");
    Log.i("Latitude",i2+"");
    Log.i("Longitude1",longitude+"");
    Log.i("Latitude1", latitude+"");
    Log.i("note",pref.getString("note"+i, null));


    if(longitude==i1&&latitude==i2) {
        String note=pref.getString("note"+i, null);
        txt.setText(note);
    }
}
```

I have no idea what types are your longitude and latitude variables. If they are primitives (double) nothing mor should be done. If they are Double objects please change them to primitives, or extract double value with `logitude.doubleValue()`